# Where is the error in this Scheme program?

Tags: scheme

I am getting "Error: Invalid lambda: (lambda (insert-all))."

```
(define permutations
 (lambda (L)
  (let
   ((insert-all
    (lambda (e Ls)
     (let
     ((insert-one
      (lambda (L)
       (letrec
        ((helper
         (lambda(L R)
         (if (null? R)
          (list (append L(list e)R))
          (helper (append L (list (car R) ) ) (cdr R) )
          ))))
          (helper '() L)))))
          (apply append(map insert-one Ls)))))))

  (cond ((null? L) '() )
  ((null?(cdr L)) (list L))
  (else (insert-all (car L) (permutations ((cdr L))))))))
```

It is supposed to return all permutations of a given list.

Comment: For what input are you getting your 'invalid lambda' error?  It is not likely that `(permutations ((cdr L)))` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form that you have provided in not valid scheme.  Specifically, your highest-level `let` form does not have a body.  You might be thinking that the `cond` clause is the body but owing to your parenthesis it is not part of the `let`.  Honestly, this is the fault of your formatting.  Here is a 'properly' formatted Scheme form:

```
(define (permutations L)
  (let ((insert-all
         (lambda (e Ls)
           (let ((insert-one
                  (lambda (L)
                    (let helper ((L '()) (R L))
                      (if (null? R)
                          (list (append L (list e) R))
                          (helper (append L (list (car R)))
                                  (cdr R)))))))
             (apply append (map insert-one Ls))))))

    (cond ((null? L)       '())
          ((null? (cdr L)) (list L))
          (else (insert-all (car L)
                            (permutations (cdr L)))))))
```

At least it compiles and runs, although it doesn't produce the right answer (although I don't know what the proper input it):

```
> (permutations '(a b c))
((c b a))
> (permutations '((a b) (1 2)))
(((1 2) (a b)))
```

Here is an implementation that works:

```
(define (permutations L)
  (define (insert-all e Ls)
    (apply append 
           (map (lambda (e) 
                  (map (lambda (x) (cons e x)) Ls))
                e)))
  (cond ((null? L)       '())
        ((null? (cdr L)) (map list (car L)))
        (else (insert-all (car L)
                          (permutations (cdr L))))))


> (permutations '((a b) (1 2) (x y)))
((a 1 x) (a 1 y) (a 2 x) (a 2 y) (b 1 x) (b 1 y) (b 2 x) (b 2 y))
```

The basic structure of your code was fine; just the implementation of your `insert-one` and `helper` were lacking.